# Asp.Net Identity 2 not able to reset password clear text?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I'm building a admin piece for a club website. I need to be able to allow someone with Admin rights to reset a users password. I also want to have the admin to be able to see the user's password in clear text because in our scenario it's easier to just tell the user what their current password is instead of going through resetting the password through email. I know that doing the two factor authentication with email confirmation would be a more secure way of doing this but I don't want to deal with user interaction and confirmation emails, at least not for now. I just need the admin to be able to reset the password directly if need be as well as just be able to see the password.

That being said I was finally able to come up with the code to do this. However, when I use the ResetPasswordAsync method in Identity it doesn't seem to update the PasswordClearText field in the AspNetUsers table. I've verified this by changing the password, logging off, logging back on with the new password, and then still see that the PasswordClearText has the original password.

Is there any way to reset the PasswordClearText?

Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> PasswordReset(MemberPasswordReset model)
{
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);

    var UserManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

    string resetToken = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
    IdentityResult passwordChangeResult = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, resetToken, model.Password);

    if(passwordChangeResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    AddErrors(passwordChangeResult);        
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I hate plain text passwords, but you seem determined in implementing that. So I'll give you a nudge in a direction of `IPasswordHasher`.

Answer (score 2):

Storing a password in clear text is **always** a bad idea. I understand the temptation because it makes your (or the admin's) life easier, however you do have a responsibility to your users that use your site.

A lot of people are lazy and will re-use the same password in multiple places, if your site stores the passwords in clear text, and gets compromised. The breach could be far worse than just your site. Not to mention the breach of privacy by having the admin see their passwords.

Comment: I understand that but there is really nothing on the site that can be compromised other notes to meetings and newletters for a car club. After all the .Net team included the field in the table and it's automatically populated when you create an account, just not when you reset the password.

Comment: I think the original purpose of the field is to send users a password when you are creating one for them the first time their account is created. As you might be required to email it to them. When the user then updates the password the field is no longer used as the password should remain hidden from that point forward

Comment: Looks like that's the case since the field isn't updated with a password reset.